# How to prepopulate a form in Stripes?

Tags: java, stripes

I have a Stripes form using an Action bean.
I can store the data without any problem out of the form, but I did not find out how to prepopulate the form's data.
I have simplified my example to show what's not working.
My code under @Before is without any effect: the data dont go into the form.
How should I manage this approach?

myform.jsp:

```
...
<stripes:form beanclass="UserActionBean">
...
<stripes:text name="user" />
<stripes:submit name="store" value="Save" />
...
</stripes:form>
...
```

ActionBean:

```
public class UserActionBean implements ActionBean {
    private String user;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        user = "myuser";
    }

    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution store() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need public getters and setters for Stripes to be able to read the value.

Although usually I would use the `@DefaultHandler` for the get, and then create a new handler for the save e.g. `@HandlesEvent(value = "save")  public Resolution save () {...`

Comment: Yes that's clear, but I do not understand how to prepopulate a form. Unfortunatelly I cannot change here the code again to show better what I want to ask.

Comment: so did you implement the getter? is `init` actually being called` Is there any errors?  What url are you calling?

Comment: Alex, the form will be pre-populated with whatever the getter in the action bean returns.

Comment: thank you both very much for your answers! my problem was not about getters and setters (their usage is mandatory anyway) but about using that stripes stuff with incept: I did not understand that at the time I asked my question. So '@Before' seems to be complitly useless without a 'LifecycleStage'

Answer (score 0):

This might be crude, but I used a getter like Scary Wombat said and initialized the variable in the ActionBean.  Or you could set its value in your handler that does the initial page display.

```
@Validate(required = true, on = {
    "proceed"
})
private String tumblrUrl= "xyz.tumblr.com";

...

public String getTumblrUrl() {
    return this.tumblrUrl;
}

public void setTumblrUrl(final String tumblrUrl) {
    this.tumblrUrl = tumblrUrl;
}
```

Comment: good luck getting any response.  Good to see stripes is not dead though.

Comment: Scary Wombat: what are people using these days if they're moving away from Stripes?